# motor barely turns over and melts ground wire,

Tags: ground, wire

Motor barely turns over and ground wire starts smoking and melts wire coating. already moved ground to different areas and this does not help.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What kind of car is this? Year/make/model/engine. Was anything changed on the vehicle to account for it?

Comment: You need to check all the battery / body, battery / engine and engine / body earth or ground straps / cables as they should not smoke or melt if they are in good condition and fitted properly. The melting / smoking shows that there is a problem somewhere.

Comment: What size ground wire do you have?  It should be very large and connected to the body and the block.  Does your positive wire get this hot?

Comment: As long as there is not anything restricting the engine, I would suggest also having the starter tested. Sounds like the it might be binding up causing excessive amp draw on the battery.

Comment: Would you by chance be able to take a picture of the melting(melted) wire for us?

Answer (score -1):

Your starter (all starters) has a dead short at zero RPM, though it’s protected somewhat by ballast.  As it rotates it generates a back EMF (voltage) that opposes the battery voltage.  Since your starter is bogged down it is drawing too much current.  That’s why it’s overheating the circuitry. Why it’s bogging isn’t clear from your description.  But if you could describe the cause, you wouldn’t be asking.

Comment: A starter is not a dead short - very low resistance but there is some otherwise the starter would not work...